# Couchbase N1QL Json Array String Wild Card Search

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

Is is possible to wild card search JSON String Array in a way similar to `%Mr.%` in N1QL . I know that exact value could be queried like `'Jon' in names` where `names` is the JSON array

```
{
    "use" : "official"
    "names" : ["Jon", "Snow", "Smith", "Mr. Smith"]
}
```

But I want to search like `%Mr.% in names` in N1QL . Is it possible ? I have tried but it failed to do so , I have also tried Regex functions but seems like it only works for key value pair not for Array Searching.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
WHERE ANY name IN names SATISFIES name LIKE '%Mr.%' END;
```

Also see

https://dzone.com/articles/a-couchbase-index-technique-for-like-predicates-wi
https://dzone.com/articles/more-than-like-efficient-json-search-with-couchbas
https://dzone.com/articles/split-and-conquer-efficient-string-search-with-n1q